# Finding limit of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am asked to show that limiting value of $\dfrac{\bar z^2}z$ is $0$ using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition when z tends to 0.

Is it alright to take $\delta=\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon>|z|$?

As we get $$\frac{\left|z\right|^{\,2}}{|z|}<\varepsilon\implies\frac{\left|\bar z\right|^2}{|z|}<\varepsilon\implies\left|\frac{\bar z^2} z\right|<\varepsilon$$ whenever $|z|<\delta$.
How can we clearly say that |z| is always greater than 0 as epsilon needs to be greater than 0.

Comment: Mathematics Stack Exchange [uses MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematical formulae. Please follow the link and familiarize yourself with LaTeX to provide better quality questions next time. I have edited your question to introduce said format. Good luck!

Comment: Besides, nowhere in your question it is mentioned at which point the limit is being taken.

Comment: Thanks for editing and extremly sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

> $$\Big| \frac{{\bar z}^2} {z}\Big|  =  \frac{|{\bar z}^2|} {|z|} = \frac{|{z}|^2} {|z|} =|z|<\epsilon =\delta. $$

So we have

> $$|z|<\delta \implies    \Big| \frac{{\bar z}^2} {z}\Big|< \epsilon.    $$

**Note:**

> $$|\bar{z} |^2 =|z|^2. $$

Answer (score 1):

We use the following relation:
$$\vert z^2\vert =z\bar{z} \implies \vert\bar{z}^2\vert=\bar{z}z$$

So we see that $$\vert\frac{\bar{z}^2}{z}-0\vert=\vert \bar{z}\vert$$ and for $z=x+iy$ going to $0$ we also have $\bar{z}=x-iy$ going to zero, so we get:

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z}=0$$

To see this using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition:

Let $\epsilon >0$ arbitrary. Then we can pick $\delta = \epsilon$ and we need to check that $ \forall z \in \mathbb C  $ such that $\vert z \vert < \delta$ we get $\vert \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z}-0\vert< \epsilon$. Now by calculations done above we see that this is indeed the case.

Comment: We have $\lvert z \rvert^2 = z \overline{z}$ and not only $z^2 = z \overline z$.

Comment: Of course, thanks sir

Comment: Is |z| always greater than 0? How can we say this?

Comment: as long as $z \neq 0$ yes, but I don't understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: We choose  epsilon a number greater than zero and here we choose epsilon to be greater than |z| but we cannot write this when z is zero.

Comment: $\vert z \vert \geq 0 \space \forall z \in \mathbb C$ and $ \epsilon > \vert z \vert$ implies $ \epsilon > 0$. $\epsilon$ is always **strictly** greater than $\vert z \vert$.